# I can't use the form information in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am learning how to use databases in Flutter and am using SQFLITE as a guide. However, when I tried implementing it, my code did not work and I received this error message:

[image]

I was following a course where I learned a lot about Dart and am now resuming Flutter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message it self is pretty obvious, you do not have a column named imagem in your database, possible reasons could be:

1. You did not create the column
2. You created it but misspelled it while creating or you are not spelling it correctly in your query.

If you did not create the column, you can use the following query to alter the table and add a column to it

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN column_name data_type;
```